# Update multiple rows with conditions

Tags: sql

I have a table ITEM like this:

```
SKU ID  SERIAL  CODE
A   0   10  aa
B   4   20  bb
C   5   30  cc
D   8   40  dd
E   8   50  ee
F   7   60  rr
```

I want to update it to this using SQL UPDATE command:

```
SKU ID  SERIAL  CODE
A   0   10  aa
B   1   20  bb
C   1   30  cc
D   8   40  dd
E   1   50  ee
F   1   60  rr
```

Lets say I have 3000 rows and I want to update 100 SKU and set the ID to 1.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Can you explain the logic you're updating the data by? It's not obvious (at least not to me) from the sample data.

Comment: Question needs a bit more details.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you can just us `in`:

```
update t
    set id = 1
    where sku in (sku1, sku2, sku3, . . .);
```

Comment: Hi Thank you for your help. It will help but i have 3000++ sku to update hehehe...